# Does visual studio let you access outside the bound of arrays? (VS2013)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I'd like a formal explanation on the stance of visual studio C++ and what it does when you create an array such as:

```
int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
```

and you then do something like:

```
cout << a[4];
```

Upon test, it will print out the garbage stored in that memory location. Why does it allow the programmer to do this, while a language like javaScript will prevent the user from doing so?

What's the prevailing philosophy by not making the compiler ban this kind of behavior from the user in C++? Is this something carried over from C?

These are just some minor curiosities that I have, and perhaps the person who answers can tell me where I'd be able to find such information. The answer as to *what* is happening is not what I'm asking, it's the *why* that I'm interested in.

Thank you.

Comment: why do you use the javascript tag?

Comment: @NinaScholz Because I mention javascript in my comment. Not sure if you saw that. I was thinking, maybe I'll also get a javaScript explanation too. Regardless, I removed the tag because zeromus sort of requested me in doing so.

Comment: The philosophy is not paying for what you don't use. That is to say, not imposing the costs of bounds checking on the developer - rather assuming the developer has already made such checks if he thinks he needs them.  Such checking *is* included in standard library constructs like std::array and std::vector, or rather can be configured to have them in either debug or release builds.

Comment: in javascript you get simply an `undefined` for indices which are not initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the compiler, but the language is defined in such a way that it's allowed. It will lead to *undefined behavior* though as the contents is *indeterminate*.

As for the *reason* it's allowed, consider the definition of the subscript (array indexing) operator (From ISO/IEC 14882:2011(E) §5.2.1/1 [expr.sub]):

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a postfix expression. One of the expressions shall have the type “***pointer to `T`***” and the other shall have unscoped enumeration or integral type. The result is an lvalue of type “`T`.” The type “`T`” shall be a completely-defined object type. The expression `E1[E2]` is identical (by definition) to `*((E1)+(E2))`

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

What happens due to the above is that the array `E1` is decayed to a pointer to the first element (i.e. it's equivalent to `&(E1)[0]`), and then the compiler performs pointer arithmetic with `(E1)+(E2)`. And since the array has decayed to a pointer, there is no possibility for bounds-checking.